# switch selected image with jquery

Tags: jquery, select, clone, appendto

I've got this codepen -

http://codepen.io/sturobson/pen/3f1cd0077301489290d9e5a6e40077b7

When you select an image write some text and click 'preview' a lightbox with the image and text comes into view.

My problem is if the user then closes the lightbox and selects a different image then both images appear. I don't want to remove the text/image on closing the lightbox (which'd be the easiest option).

Also I've noticed that if you click the select button a few times it 'breaks' and gives a blue background w/ the word select. Not sure how to fix that.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

edit, adding code (apologies for not doing this to start with)...

The code to add a class to the selected image, this gives a blue background to the word 'select' and clones the image into a different div

```
  $('.selectable-image').on("click", function() {
    $('.selectable-image.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(".previewimage img").remove();
        $(".selected > img").first().clone().appendTo(".preview-image");

    return false;
  });
```

This code changes the word to select or selected depending on clicking

```
  $('.selectable-image').on("click", function() {
    $('.select-photo', this).text(function(_, oldText) {
        return oldText === 'SELECTED' ? 'SELECT' : 'SELECTED';
    }).parent().siblings().find('.select-photo').text(function(){
        return $(this).data('text');
    })
    return false;
  });
```

With these two I need to figure out how to change remove the 'selected' class if I click the same element twice. Also I want to swap the image appended if I click one then click a different one, removing the first image and replacing it with the new selection.

I hope that makes sense on a Sunday morning.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — **in the question itself**. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `appendTo()` which is quite likely appending the image to the lightbox rather than updating it. Try using `attr("src")` to update the source of the  rather than appending a new one.